# what is the difference between int &val2 = val and int val3 = val?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

I'm new to C++ and is trying to learn the concept of reference. Could someone please tell me what is the difference between  int &val2 = val and int val3 = val?

I understand that I am creating a reference to val with &val2 (val2 is not an object, but merely a reference to an object). Is it the same with val3? Or am I creating something completely different?

```
int val = 1034;

int &val2 = val;
int val3 = val;
```

Comment: By changing the value of `val2`, the value of `val` will be changed and vice versa. But `val3` is an independent variable that just initialized by `val`'s value.

Comment: so val3 is an different object compared to val?

Comment: Yes. It's completely different.

Comment: @deepmax thanks for the help! really appreciate it!